# NumericUpDown Saving in setting

Tags: numericupdown

I have a couple of `NumericUpDown` controls in my form and I want to save them to settings.
It only worked if I used `DataBinding`, but then it saves each control as decimal each under a new name.
Is it possible to save all the numeric controls under one collection name in the settings? And reload the values when the forms open again?

Comment: show some code you tried so far

Comment: @ migea I stored before the controls in design mode and then databinding. This I have for my textboxes  Sub SavingForm()
        textBoxes = New TextBox() {TextBoxStock1, TextBoxStock2, TextBoxStock3, TextBoxStock4}
        With My.Settings
            If .StockSave Is Nothing Then .StockSave = New System.Collections.Specialized.StringCollection
            For i = 0 To textBoxes.Length - 1
                If .StockSave.Count <= i Then .StockSave.Add("")
                textBoxes(i).Text = .StockSave(i)
            Next
        End With
    End Sub Thats what I Have for my textboxes.